# deploy application to glassfish throw ant tasks

Tags: eclipse, ant, glassfish-3

i´m trying  to deploy a web application to my glassfish server 3 throw ant task . I found the follow task on oracle web site documentation(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beaep/)  sun-appserv-deploy ,  but it doesn’t work , it shows this error

BUILD FAILED
C:\MarcoDesenvolve\Atendimento\Exemp\build.xml:172: Problem: failed to create task or type sun-appserv-deploy
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

My code in build.xml is this

```
                        <sun-appserv-deploy
                                         name="Exemp"
                                         force="true"
                                         precompilejsp="false"
                                         verify="false"
                                         upload="true"
                                         user="marco"
                                         passwordfile="${marco}"
                                         host="localhost"
                                         port="4848"
                                         target="${Exemp}"
                                         asinstalldir="${env.ANT_HOME}" />

                        </target>
```

I don´t know what i´m doing wrong, if is about the attributes, or the configuration of the project. Pleas if someone has more experience with ant Task could give me an idea of which error is this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed the first step of the document to which you gave a link: "Setting Up Your Ant Environment". The Ant tasks for Glassfish are in a jar file called `sun-appserv-ant.jar`. Then you need to define the tasks in your build script, using the appropriate `<taskdef> ... </taskdef>` statements. After that, you should be good to go.